# Rethrow an error from within SSIS package

Tags: error-handling, ssis, rethrow

Ive got a 2010 SSIS package which in turn runs other packages.  Each package is independent so if one fails the others can still progress.  My logic states the next one run on completion of the previous one wether it failed or not

My proble is that when one does error i get a very standard error message which doesn't tell me which one crashed or give me any other clues.

The  Integrated Services Dashboard does assist but still lacking basic information.  But what i would like is that the package rethrow the error so i can add some more ifnormation to it.

How is this done?

Do i create a script task in the Onerror event for the individual package and add some information of my own before rethrowing the error ?

Any examples that show you what needs to be done ?  I still want the other packets to continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that there is no 2010 version of SSIS. You are using Visual Studio 2010 against either 2008 R2 or 2012 but this does not affect the question in any way.

The best way to capture this error information is to log the error information in the child packages. This can be implemented using an SSIS frameworks such as

Free - http://ssisetlframework.codeplex.com/

Commercial product - http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress

Using these frameworks you could easily get the detailed error information that you need without having to modify the control package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The VS2012 Templates for Integration Services Project were release by microsoft late last year. Project was started in vs2010 with sql2012 backend.  I cannot rewrite the application to include the BI Monkey SSIS ETL Framework.  Nor can I purchase a 3rd party product. We have a strict development environment and architecture policy which all developers must adhere to.  I have what I have.  Just wanted to hook into the default error object which goes to the sQL agent and add name of current package and file being process.